# Calling `open` on an in-memory buffer

Tags: python

I want to upload a file to GCS using the Airflow client (`airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs.FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`). It wants a string which is a file path to a local file (which it passes to `open`). However, I don't exactly have a local file. I have the file contents in memory as a string. I *could* write that to a file, upload it , and delete the file, but I would prefer to avoid all that and just have the client read from memory. Is there something that I can pass to `open` to get it to read from an in-memory buffer instead of the filesystem?

Comment: Hmm. Does the result need to be a seekable file descriptor? If not, you could use `os.pipe`, pass the read end as a `/dev/fd/##` descriptor (if you're only targeting sufficiently Linux-flavored operating systems), and have a thread that writes your content to the write end.

Comment: The library just calls `read` on it.

Comment: Great, then, the FIFO hack I described above ought to work (That said -- what operating systems are you targeting? If this is code intended to run on non-Linux-y hosts, that changes things a bit).